# local variable 'count' defined in enclosing scope on line 10 referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having an issue with the following code of Python 3 (the line at 5th position from bottom *count=count+1*):

```py
import base64
import json
from google.cloud import iot_v1
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
count = 0


def device_config(config):
    client = iot_v1.DeviceManagerClient()
    name = client.device_path(<project_ID>,
                              <Region>,  <Registry>, <Device_ID>)
    binary_data = bytes(config, 'utf-8')
    client.modify_cloud_to_device_config(name, binary_data)


def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    if 'data' in event:
        data = event['data']
        data = base64.b64decode(data)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        data = json.loads(data)

        temperature = float(data['temperature'])

        if temperature > 25.0:
            device_config("ledon")
            if count < 1:
                client.calls.create( \
                    url=<URL>,
                    to=os.environ['TWILIO_TO'],
                    from_=os.environ['TWILIO_FROM'])
                count = count+1
        else:
            device_config("ledoff")
    else:
        print("Data is not present!")
```

This function will be called continuously (imagine like an infinite loop will call this function). I want to update count by 1 when first time temperature goes above 25 and for later calls, how high it may go, LED should be on, but calling shouldnot be done

Comment: You need to add `global count` on the first line of the `hello_pubsub` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in `hello_pubsub(event, context)` you assign to `count` in the line `count = count+1`. which makes python look for `count` in the function scope (where it has not been defined and therefore lookup on the right-hand-side [`count+1`] fails).

this might be a worhty read: https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime

you need to tell python that you mean the global `count`:

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    global count
    ...
```

---

probably cleaner would be:

```
def hello_pubsub(count, event, context):
    ...
```

and then call it using:

```
hello_pubsub(count, event, context)
```

Comment: I wouldn't encourage using globals

Comment: @JammyDodger neither would i (in general). but this explains the error and would fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing `count` inside a function, whereas it is defined outside. You should pass `count` as a parameter.

Comment: would it work if they were to make it a global variable

Comment: Sorry, but why are globals so bad?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `count` into the function as a parameter, and increment it in the loop that will call the function. If you absolutely need to assign to it within the function, you can use the statement `global count` before you do the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a local variable into another function. You also need to pass the variable into the function. Hope this helps!

```
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
global count = 0



def hello_pubsub(event, context,count):
```